# Scroll upto specific content inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll up to text content ({{'some text....'}} this text will depend on backend response) inside a div if the content present. below is my code. It is working when it applies to HTML, body. but I want to apply it to the ".m-portlet__body" div.

```
<body>
<div class="m-portlet__body">
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            let errors = [];
            let textValues = $('.form-control-feedback').map((i, el) => el.innerText.trim()).get();
            $.each(textValues, function( index, value ) {
                if(value !== ''){
                    errors.push(value)
                }
            });

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('*:contains('+errors[0]+'):last').offset().top-150
            }, 1000);
            console.log(errors[0]);
        });
    </script>
```

How can I do that? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <body>
<div class="m-portlet__body">
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{'some text....'}}</div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            let errors = [];
            let textValues = $('.form-control-feedback').map((i, el) => el.innerText.trim()).get();
            $.each(textValues, function( index, value ) {
                if(value !== ''){
                    errors.push(value)
                }
            });

            $('.m-portlet__body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('*:contains('+errors[0]+'):last').offset().top-150
            }, 1000);
            console.log(errors[0]);
        });
    </script>
```

refer this fiidle for working example [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/shafeequetp/8fbg01uL/1/)